# Get Array of dates using Jquery MVC3

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, asp.net-mvc-3, date

Guys I'm using JQuery UI date picker plugin for Reservation system. For this, I'm checking already booked dates using following script:

```
var bookedDays = ["2013-5-3", "2013-5-4"];
function assignCalendar(id) {
    $('<div class="calendar" />').insertAfter($(id)).datetimepicker({
       altFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
           altTimeFormat: "hh:mm tt",
           useLocalTimezone: true,
           minDate: new Date(),
           maxDate: '+1y',
           altField: id,
           altFieldTimeOnly: false,
           showButtonPanel: false,
           firstDay: 1,
           dayNamesMin: ['S', 'M', 'T', 'W', 'T', 'F', 'S'],
           beforeShowDay: isAvailable
        });
      }

      function isAvailable(date) {
         var dateAsString = date.getFullYear().toString() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1).toString() + "-" + date.getDate();
         var result = $.inArray(dateAsString, bookedDays) == -1 ? [true] : [false];
         return result;
     }
```

This is working fine. But, what I need is loading booked dates dynamically from DB as an array and pass that to above function. I tried the following But not getting the proper values.

Here's my Controller code:

```
public JsonResult GetBookedDates(int resourceTypeID=1)
        {
            var dates = new List<string>();

            var resources = _db.Resources.Where(r => r.ResourceTypeID == resourceTypeID);
            foreach (var resource in resources)
            {
                Resource resource1 = resource;

                var reservedDates = _db.Reservations.Where(rv => rv.ResourceID == resource1.ID);
                foreach (var reservedDate in reservedDates)
                {
                    for (DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(reservedDate.Booked); dt <= Convert.ToDateTime(reservedDate.Checkout); dt = dt.AddDays(1))
                    {
                        dates.Add("\"" + dt.Year + "-" + dt.Month + "-" + dt.Day + "\"");
                        //dates.Add(dt.Year + "-" + dt.Month + "-" + dt.Day);
                        //dates.Add("\"" + dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "\"");
                    }
                }
            }
            return Json(dates, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

And Modified JQuery function:

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: "/Home/GetBookedDates?resourceTypeID=1",
            traditional: true,
            success: function (data) {
                var bookedDays = data // --> Here I need the array of booked dates
                assignCalendar('#date_in_input');
                assignCalendar('#date_out_input');

                function assignCalendar(id) {
                    $('<div class="calendar" />').insertAfter($(id)).datetimepicker({
                        altFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
                        altTimeFormat: "hh:mm tt",
                        useLocalTimezone: true,
                        minDate: new Date(),
                        maxDate: '+1y',
                        altField: id,
                        altFieldTimeOnly: false,
                        showButtonPanel: false,
                        firstDay: 1,
                        dayNamesMin: ['S', 'M', 'T', 'W', 'T', 'F', 'S'],
                        beforeShowDay: isAvailable
                    });
                }

                function isAvailable(date) {
                    var dateAsString = date.getFullYear().toString() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1).toString() + "-" + date.getDate();
                    var result = $.inArray(dateAsString, bookedDays) == -1 ? [true] : [false];
                    return result;
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

Please help me to solve this

Comment: What does console.log(bookedDays) show?

Comment: @Michael_B firebug showing the json as ["2013-5-10","2013-5-12"] but still the algorithm not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your problem is that you have the datepicker function inside `assignCalendar` which needs to be called.  You either need to have it called directly after the load or pull out the `function assignCalendar(id){...and enclose the ajax call here...}`

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: "/Home/GetBookedDates?resourceTypeID=1",
        traditional: true,
        success: function (data) {
            var bookedDays = data // --> Here I need the array of booked dates
            assignCalendar('#date_in_input');
            assignCalendar('#date_out_input');
            $('<div class="calendar" />').insertAfter($(id)).datetimepicker({
                altFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
                altTimeFormat: "hh:mm tt",
                useLocalTimezone: true,
                minDate: new Date(),
                maxDate: '+1y',
                altField: id,
                altFieldTimeOnly: false,
                showButtonPanel: false,
                firstDay: 1,
                dayNamesMin: ['S', 'M', 'T', 'W', 'T', 'F', 'S'],
                beforeShowDay: function (date) {
                    var dateAsString = date.getFullYear().toString() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1).toString() + "-" + date.getDate();
                    var result = $.inArray(dateAsString, bookedDays) == -1 ? [true] : [false];
                    return result;
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

**UPDATE**

Your service is returning the dates with a leading `0`.  You should be able to just use this instead:

```
dates.Add("\"" + dt.ToString("yyyy-M-d") + "\"");
```

Comment: If I pass  `var bookedDays = ["2013-5-3", "2013-5-10"];` it works fine. but passing dynamic data say `var bookedDays = [data]` is not working

Comment: Place a `console.log(bookedDays)` and `console.log(dateAsString)` before `return result;` in `beforeShowDay`.  What do they show?

Comment: dateAsString: `2013-4-29` 
bookedDays:`2013-05-03,2013-05-04,2013-05-05,2013-06-10,2013-06-11`

And `dateAsString` repeats for each day in a calender

Comment: Notice the `04`  that's probable preventing a match.

Comment: Solved! thanks.... I made it in ugly way, `matching 20130429 with 20130503, 20130504` and so on.. removed '-' char from dates...